# Rails Rspec showing different results than console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, rspec-rails

I have a feature which works fine in production and in development, but the test I wrote for it doesn't pass. It seems like the data is not persisting, although when I use byebug it shows that it's fine.

Here's my spec:

```
  it "cancels a user plan" do
    plan = FactoryBot.create(:plan, name: 'MOMLab', paypal_id: 'MOMLab15')
    user = FactoryBot.create(:user, email: 'payer@email.com',
                                    payer_id: '6M5AMEDMVMSNL')
    user_plan = FactoryBot.create(:user_plan, user: user, plan: plan, end_date: nil)
    ipn = FactoryBot.create(:ipn, :cancelation)
    sign_in FactoryBot.create(:user, :admin)
    visit ipn_path(ipn)
    expect(user_plan.status).to eq('Active')
    click_on 'Process'
    sleep 10
    expect(ipn.reload.complete?).to be_truthy
    expect(user_plan.reload.end_date.to_date).to eq(Time.zone.now.to_date)
    expect(user_plan.status).to eq('Canceled')
  end
```

Here's the code:

```
def cancel_subscription
  @user = find_user
  @user_plan = @plan.user_plans.where(user: @user).active.first
  if @user_plan
    @user_plan.end_date = Time.zone.now
    @user_plan.status = 'Canceled'
    @user_plan.save!
    if @user_plan.persisted?
      @ipn.update(complete: true)
    else
      handle_errors("User plan didn't save")
    end
  else
    handle_errors("Couldn't find subscription")
  end
end
```

I put the object with `inspect` during the execution and in the test - in the execution it appears like everything is okay and changes have persisted (it goes into the persisted? tree, but outside in the test it shows as if the object has never been saved.

Any ideas?

Edit:

Here's my `rails_helper.rb`:

```
require 'spec_helper'
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
abort("The Rails environment is running in production mode!") if Rails.env.production?
require 'rspec/rails'
require "capybara/rspec"
require 'devise'

Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome)
end

Capybara.register_driver :headless_chrome do |app|
  caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(loggingPrefs: { browser: 'ALL' })
  opts = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
  chrome_args = %w[--headless --no-sandbox --disable-gpu --window-size=1920,1080 --remote-debugging-port=9222]
  chrome_args.each { |arg| opts.add_argument(arg) }
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome, options: opts, desired_capabilities: caps)
end
Capybara.javascript_driver = :headless_chrome
Capybara.current_driver = :headless_chrome
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
  config.include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers, type: :feature
  config.include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers, type: :request
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
  config.include Warden::Test::Helpers
  Warden.test_mode!
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
  config.filter_rails_from_backtrace!
end
```

and my `spec_helper.rb`:

```
require 'webmock/rspec'
require 'capybara/rspec'
include WebMock::API
require 'etsy'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  Capybara.default_max_wait_time = 10

  Capybara.register_driver :insecure_selenium do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(
    app,
    browser: :firefox,
    desired_capabilities: { accept_insecure_certs: true }
  )
  end

  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end
  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end
  config.shared_context_metadata_behavior = :apply_to_host_groups
begin
  config.filter_run_when_matching :focus
  config.example_status_persistence_file_path = "spec/examples.txt"
  config.disable_monkey_patching!
  if config.files_to_run.one?
    config.default_formatter = "doc"
  end=
  config.profile_examples = 3
  Kernel.srand config.seed
 end
end
```

Comment: What version of Rails are you using?

Comment: Hey @ThomasWalpole, I'm using Rails 6

Comment: Then could you add your test configuration (capybara/rspec/etc) code to your question.  Rails 6 should be sharing the DB connection between the app and the tests (assuming you're letting Capybara run the app under test).  What you're seeing is most likely because that connection isn't being shared, and the tests are doing all their DB calls inside a transaction which is never actually committed. (Note: mixing UI system tests with DB/Object verifications is generally a bad idea)

Comment: Thanks for the insight, @ThomasWalpole. I'm using RSpec + Capybara, is there any config files you want to look at? All my other tests are running okay. I'm eager to learn, what kind of test would you use to test the functionality of a website button that works on a db object?

Comment: Add the relevant sections of whichever files you're configuring Capybara and RSpec in - (spec_helper.rb/rails_helper.rb/etc).  Feature tests/specs should generally test from a users perspective - so you test that the UI becomes what is expected, as opposed to DB objects.  If you want to verify that specific requests make changes in the DB then you should do that in requests specs - verifying that a button changes a specific db object is mixing concerns. (Also note that `save!` raises on failure, so your `persisted?` check should never be false)

Comment: @ThomasWalpole thank you so much! I'll get working on splitting the concerns. I really appreciate all your help. Also, added the config files just in case you would be so kind as to take a look anyway.

Comment: Hmmm, I don't see anything concerning in those configs, you're not setting Capybara.app_host or Capybara.run_server to anything non-default.

Comment: @ThomasWalpole nope :(

Comment: @ThomasWalpole rewrote it as a request and for some reason it now works. Thanks a ton :)